# Created Pagination Grabbing Incorrect Index Once you go to next pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of articles (105) that i paginated with 10 articles per page. All seems fine on the first page and i am able to go to the next pages with the correct content, but when i click an article on page 2 and onward it is grabbing the index of the very first article in the array.

```
<div class="news-article-list">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(article, index) in allArticles" :key="index">
       <a @click="showArticle(index)">
         <img :src="article.featureImg" v-if="article.featureImg" alt="Article Feature Image" />
         <h2 class="news-title">{{ article.title }}</h2>
         <p class="news-date">{{ article.date }}</p>
         <p class="short-desc">{{ article.shortDesc }}...</p>
       </a>
       <a class="read-more" @click="showArticle(index)">Read More</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item">
     <button type="button" class="page-link" v-show="page != 1" @click="page--">&lt;</button>
   </li>
   <li id="page-numbers">
      <button type="button" class="page-link" v-for="pageNumber in pages" @click="page = pageNumber">{{pageNumber}}</button>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item">
     <button type="button" class="page-link" v-show="page < pages.length" @click="page++">&gt;</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

the showArticle function:

```
showArticle: function showArticle(selected) {
  this.selectedArticle = selected;
  window.location = this.filteredArticles[this.selectedArticle].url;
}
```

to explain my array a little more, once the page is "created" i put it in a new array called filteredArticles as i have functions that are in place for filtering based on category, which is why you see the window.location is equal to this.filteredArticles.

My Pagination js:

```
data: function() {
  return {
   filteredArticles: [],
   timer: null,
   page: 1,
   currentPage: 1,
   perPage: 10,
   pages: [],
   articles: [
        {
          title: 'title here',
          date: 'date here',
          shortDesc: 'description here',
          url: 'url to article - had to put each article into a separate file',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        },
        {}
   ] 
},
computed: {
  allArticles() {
    return this.paginate(this.filteredArticles);
  }
},
setPages() {
  let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.filteredArticles.length / this.perPage);
    for (let index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {
        this.pages.push(index);
    }
},
paginate(filteredArticles) {
  let page = this.page;
  let perPage = this.perPage;
  let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
  let to = (page * perPage);

  return filteredArticles.slice(from, to);
},
watch: {
  filteredArticles() {
     this.setPages();
  }
}
```

I know that I may have done this in a round about way, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, but overall I just need to be able to select any of the articles and it find the correct index and direct you to the correct article no matter what page you are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to clean up and simplify your code. I removed the "round-about-ness" that you mentioned and renamed the variables to make more sense (at least to me).

Also, if you need to change the location anyway, so we're not in a single page app, why not use the anchor tag as intended with an `href` attribute, with the added bonus of accessibility?

You won't see any change when clickin an article in this demo, because I set the URLs simply to hashes ( `#1`, `#2`, etc.), but you'll see the resulting URL chaning with each article in the bottom left corner of your browser.

```js
const app = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      timer: null,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 2,
      pages: [],
      articles: [{
          title: 'Title 1',
          date: 'date article 1',
          shortDesc: 'description article 1',
          url: '/#1',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title 2',
          date: 'date article 2',
          shortDesc: 'description article 2',
          url: '#2',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title 3',
          date: 'date article 3',
          shortDesc: 'description article 3',
          url: '#3',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title 4',
          date: 'date article 4',
          shortDesc: 'description article 4',
          url: '#4',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title 5',
          date: 'date here',
          shortDesc: 'description here',
          url: '#5',
          category: 'category',
          featureImg: 'Image for article'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pagedArticles() {
      let page = this.currentPage;
      let perPage = this.perPage;
      let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
      let to = (page * perPage);

      return this.articles.slice(from, to);
    }
  }
};
Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
```

```css
nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.news-article-list li>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="p in Math.ceil( articles.length / perPage )"><button :disabled="currentPage === p" @click="currentPage = p">{{ p }}</buttpn></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
  <div class="news-article-list">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(article, index) in pagedArticles" :key="index">
        <a :href="article.url">
          <img :src="article.featureImg" v-if="article.featureImg" alt="Article Feature Image" />
          <h2 class="news-title">{{ article.title }}</h2>
          <p class="news-date">{{ article.date }}</p>
          <p class="short-desc">{{ article.shortDesc }}...</p>
          <span class="read-more">Read More</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh i realize i didn't paste the code of the buttons

Comment: Where is pagedArticles coming from? I am not seeing where that is referenced!

Comment: Glad everything cleared itself up - much more compact, isn't it? Feel free to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing indexes of two arrays: allArticles and filteredArticles. Thy have different content and indexes. To get the correct index of an element you can use findIndex:

```
showArticle(selected) {
  let index = this.filteredArticles.findIndex(el => el.id === this.allArticles[selected].id)
  this.selectedArticle = index;
  window.location = this.filteredArticles[index].url;
}
```

Comment: hmm i added this code and it still seems to grab the first article in the array!